# How to find rows of same value in SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, matching

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
   sub_aminer_paper
WHERE 
   p_abstract LIKE (
                    SELECT 
                       p_abstract
                    FROM 
                       sub_aminer_paper
                    GROUP BY 
                       p_abstract
                    HAVING 
                       COUNT(pid) > 1
                    )
AND 
   pid IN (784502,787096,789536)
ORDER BY
   pid
```

From which I want to retrieve rows having same value for column `p_abstract` where data type for `p_abstract` column in `text`. While executing this query, I got following error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this is what you are expecting.

```
SELECT *
FROM sub_aminer_paper
WHERE pid IN (784502,787096,789536)
and CAST(p_abstract AS varchar(max)) in (
    SELECT CAST(p_abstract AS varchar(max))
    FROM   sub_aminer_paper
    WHERE pid IN (784502,787096,789536)
    Group BY CAST(p_abstract AS varchar(max))
    having count(*) > 1)
ORDER by pid
```

Comment: Data type of column `p_abstract` as mentioned in the query i.e. `text`

Comment: I casted the text field to varchar(max) now. Can you try and let me know if it goes thru

Comment: Yeah now its fine @PK20, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare checksums of text fields

```
WITH PAPERS AS(
    SELECT 
           pid,
           BINARY_CHECKSUM(p_abstract) as chksum
        FROM 
           sub_aminer_paper
), DOUBLES AS (
    SELECT 
        chksum
        ,qty = COUNT(*)
      FROM
         papers
      GROUP BY
        chksum
      HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT *
    FROM 
        PAPERS P
        JOIN DOUBLES D ON P.chksum = D.chksum
```